# How to integrate with relational operators in SymPy?

Tags: python, sympy

I want to integrate sin((a-b)*x) along x from 0 to pi/4 in sympy. It gives me a piecewise answer for when (a-b)!=0 and (a-b)=0. How do I integrate only for the condition that (a-b)!=0?

I tried the following code with the relational operator but it didn't help.

```
from sympy import *
a, b, x = symbols("a b x")
Rel(a, b, "ne")
integrate(sin((a-b)*x),(x,pi/4))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `conds="none"` inside the `integrate` command:

```
integrate(sin((a-b)*x),(x,pi/4), conds="none")
```

Alternatively, you can extract the piece you are interested in from a piecewise result, by exploring its arguments:

```
res = integrate(sin((a-b)*x),(x,pi/4), conds="none")
final = res.args[0][0]
```

Edit: Note that the command `Rel(a, b, "ne")` does nothing. It just creates an unequality that is never being used.